# SQL Server How to add a linked server to the same instance without performance impact

Tags: sql-server, performance, linked-server

in my company, we have several environments with MS SQL database servers (SQL 2008 R2, SQL 2014). For the sake of simplicity, let us consider just a TEST environment and a PROD environment and two sql servers in each. Let the servers be called **srTest1**, **srTest2**, **srProd1**, **srProd2** and each be running a default MS SQL Server instance. We work with multiple databases, say DataDb, ReportDb, DWHDb.

We want to keep the same source code in T-SQL for both TEST and PROD, but the problem is the architecture or distribution of the above mentioned databases in each environment:

TEST:

- **srTest1** - DataDb
- **srTest2** - DWHDb, ReportDb

PROD:

- **srProd1** - DataDb, ReportDb
- **srProd2** - DWHDb

Now, say, in ReportDb, we write stored procedures with many SELECTs referencing tables and other objects in DataDb and DWHDb. In order to have source code as universal as possible, we decided to create linked servers for each database on each db server in each environment and name them with respect to the database they're created for. Therefore, there'll be these linked servers:

- lnkDataDb, lnkReportDb and lnkDWHDb on **srTest1**,
- lnkDataDb, lnkReportDb and lnkDWHDb on **srTest2**,
- lnkDataDb, lnkReportDb and lnkDWHDb on **srProd1**,
- lnkDataDb, lnkReportDb and lnkDWHDb on **srProd2**.

And we'll adjust the source in the stored procs accordingly. For instance:

Instead of

```
SELECT * FROM DataDb.dbo.Contact
```

We'll write

```
SELECT * FROM lnkDataDb.DataDb.dbo.Contact
```

The example above is reasonable for a situation where the database from which you execute the query (ReportDb) lies on a different server than that with the referenced table (DataDb). Which is the case for the TEST environment. But not so in PROD. It is performance I'm here concerned about. The SQL Server will treat that SELECT as a "remote query" no matter whether, in fact, it is a reference to a local object or not.

**Now, it comes the most important part:**

If you check these 3 queries for their actual execution plans, you'll see an interesting thing:

```
(1) SELECT * FROM DataDb.dbo.Contact
(2) SELECT * FROM srProd1.DataDb.dbo.Contact
(3) SELECT * FROM lnkDataDb.DataDb.dbo.Contact
```

The first two (query #1 and #2) have the same execution plan (the fastest possible) even if you use the four-part name manner of referencing the table Contact in #2.
The last query has a different plan (remote query, thus slower).

**The question is:**

*Can you somehow create a linked server to self (the same sql server instance, the default instance actually) as an "alias" to the name of the host (**srProd1**) in order for the SQL server to be forced to understand it as local and not issue "remote execution" plans?*

Thanks a lot for any hints

Pavel

Answer (score 2):

Recently I found a workaround which seems to solve this kind of issues more efficiently and more elegantly than the solution with self-pointing linked servers.

If you work (making reports, for example) with multiple databases on multiple SQL servers and the physical distribution of the databases on the servers is a challenge since it may differ from one environment to another (e.g. TEST vs PROD), I suggest this:

Use three-part db object names whenever possible. If the objects are local, then execution plans are also local, and thus effective.

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM DataDb.dbo.Contact
```

If you happen to run the above query from within a different SQL server instance (residing on a different physical machine, for example, but this not necessarily, the other SQL server instance could be installed even on the same machine), briefly if you're about to use a four-part name:

```
SELECT * FROM lnkDataDb.DataDb.dbo.Contact
```

Then you can circumvent that using the following trick:

Let's assume **lnkDataDb** points to **srTest2** and you're executing your queries from **srTest1**. Now, you'll create a "fake" database **DataDb** on your local server (**srTest1**). This fake DataDb shall contain no real db objects (no tables, no views, no stored procedures, no UDFs etc.). There shall only be synonyms defined in it. (And there also shall be the same schemas in it as those in the real DataDb on srTest2). These synonyms shall be named exactly the same way as their real db-object counterparts in DataDb on **srTest2**. Example:

```
-- To be executed on srTest1.

EXEC sp_addlinkedserver
  @server       = N'lnkDataDb',
  @srvproduct   = N'',
  @provider     = N'SQLNCLI',
  @datasrc      = N'srTest2'
;
GO

CREATE DATABASE [DataDb];
GO

USE [DataDb];
GO

CREATE SYNONYM dbo.Contact FOR lnkDataDb.DataDb.dbo.Contact;
GO
```

Now, if you want to SELECT rows from the table **dbo.Contact** residing in the database **DataDb** on **srTest2** and you're executing your query from **srTest1**, you'll use a simple three-part table name:

```
SELECT * FROM DataDb.dbo.Contact
```

Of course, on **srTest1**, this is not a table, that's just a synonym referencing the same-named table on **srTest2**. However, that's the trick, you use the same query syntax as if you were executing it on **srTest2** where the real db object resides.

There are disadvantages of this approach:

1. On the local server, at the beginning, there must not be a database
   with the same name as the remote one. Because you're about to create
   a "fake" database with that name to reflect the names of remote
   db objects.
2. You're creating one database that is almost empty, thus
   increasing the mess of various databases residing on your local
   SQL server. This might provoke reluctance of your database admin
   if they prefer having as few databases as possible.
3. If you're developing your T-SQL scripts in SQL Server Management
   Studio, for example, using synonyms cuts you off from the convenience
   of the IntelliSense feature.

Advantages outweigh the above-mentioned disadvantages, though:

1. Your scripts work in any environment (DEV, TEST, PROD) without
   the need to change any part of the source code.
2. If the other database you're querying data from resides on the same
   SQL server instance as your script, you also use the three-part name
   convention and your SQL server evaluates the query in execution plan
   as local which is OK. (This is what the original question of this
   post was searching to solve.)
3. If the other database you're querying data from resides on another
   SQL server instance, you still use a "local syntax manner" of a SQL
   query (with the synonym) which, only at runtime, evaluates in
   a remote execution plan. Which is also fine because the db object
   actually is remote.

**To summarize**

The query executes as local if the referenced object is local, the query executes as remote if the referenced object is remote, but ***the T-SQL script is always the same***. You don't have to change a letter in it.

Answer (score 0):

yes we can do this in easiest way and it worked for me.

**step 1**: In SSMS local sql server go to Server Objects -> Linked servers -> New Linked Server
**step 2**: in general tab
linked server: .
Server type: Sql Server
**step 3**: in security tab
select 'be made using the login's current security context' and click OK.
**step 4**: validate it with the below
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY([.], 'SELECT * FROM lnkdbname.schemaname.table1')

ref: https://www.kodyaz.com/sql-server-2012/create-local-linked-server-in-sql-server.aspx